# Generator function does not pause execution if I call a non generator function inside of it

Tags: javascript, redux, generator, redux-saga, yield

I have a saga that creates a nesting of setTimeout to post messages via axios like this (for this I call a non generator function in my saga):

```
import { call, put, takeLatest } from "redux-saga/effects";
import * as Action from "./action";
import axios from "axios";
import { SEND_MESSAGES } from "./constant";

function setTimeoutMessage(messageInfo) {
    let index = 0;
    setTimeout(function(){tick(index, messageInfo)}, messageInfo[index].delay);
}

function tick(index, messageInfo) {
    // send message to server
    axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:3000/send", null, {
        params: {
            ip: messageInfo[index].ip,
            port: messageInfo[index].port,
            message: messageInfo[index].message
        }
    })

    ++index;
    
    if (index < messageInfo.length) {
        setTimeout(function(){tick(index, messageInfo)}, messageInfo[index].delay);
    }
}

function* sendMessages(action) {
    try {
        // send message to server
        yield call(setTimeoutMessage, action.messageInfos)
        
        yield put(Action.sendMessageSuccess());
        yield put(Action.setIsRunning(false));
        console.log("end try")  //I've also try with 'yield console.log("end try")'
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(Action.sendMessageFailed(error));
        yield put(Action.setIsRunning(false));
        console.log("end catch")  //also try with 'yield console.log("end catch")'
    }
}

function* defaultSaga() {
    yield takeLatest(SEND_MESSAGES, sendMessages);
}

export default defaultSaga;
```

At runtime, the saga executes the `yield call(setTimeoutMessage, action.messageInfos)` but before the setTimeout of the non generator function executes, the following actions of the saga are executed (`console.log()` and `yield put`).

To solve this problem I tried to implement `yield race` as below, but I get the same result as before, and the constants assigned to the race are all undefined (even when I’m sure to dispatch the `CANCEL` action)

```
import { call, put, takeLatest, race, take } from "redux-saga/effects";
import * as Action from "./action";
import axios from "axios";
import { SEND_MESSAGES, CANCEL } from "./constant";

function setTimeoutMessage(messageInfo) {
    console.log('enter non generator function')
    let index = 0;
    setTimeout(function(){tick(index, messageInfo)}, messageInfo[index].delay);
}

function tick(index, messageInfo) {
    console.log('timeout stuff')
    // send message to server
    axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:3000/send", null, {
        params: {
            ip: messageInfo[index].ip,
            port: messageInfo[index].port,
            message: messageInfo[index].message
        }
    })

    ++index;
    
    if (index < messageInfo.length) {
        setTimeout(function(){tick(index, messageInfo)}, messageInfo[index].delay);
    }
}

function* sendMessages(action) {
    const { task, cancel } = yield race({
        task: call(setTimeoutMessage, action.messageInfos),
        cancel: take(CANCEL)
    })

    console.log("after race", task, cancel)

    if (cancel) {
        let id = window.setTimeout(function() {}, 0);

        while (id--) {
            window.clearTimeout(id); 
        }
    } else if (task) {
        yield put(Action.sendMessageSuccess());
    } else {
        console.log("in if condition nothing ")
        yield put(Action.sendMessageFailed());
    }
    console.log("after yield race + check what effect succeed ")
    yield put(Action.setIsRunning(false));
}

function* defaultSaga() {
    yield takeLatest(SEND_MESSAGES, sendMessages);
}

export default defaultSaga;
```

This second implementation gives me the following result in the console:

```
enter non generator function

after race undefined undefined

in if condition nothing 

timeout stuff
```

The `console.log("after yield race + check what effect succeed ")` at the end of my saga function is never displayed

I get the same result if I let my task happen or if I dispatch the `CANCEL` action from the beginning

What causes this behavior? How do you force the saga to execute the `yield call` before executing the rest of the instructions in the saga?

PS: I don’t use redux-toolkit because I add a feature to an existing code using a relatively old version of redux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not yield or return any promise, that generator should wait for. Refactor your function to a saga, and use the `delay` saga effect to wait for the next tick:

```
const postApiMessage = params =>
  axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:3000/send", null, { params });

function* setTimeoutMessage(messageInfo) {
  let index = 0;

  while (index < messageInfo.length) {
    const { delay: timeout, ip, port, message } = messageInfo[index];

    yield call(postApiMessage, { ip, port, message });

    index++;

    yield delay(timeout);
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
function* sendMessages(action) {
  try {
    // send message to server
    yield setTimeoutMessage(action.messageInfos);

    yield put(Action.sendMessageSuccess());
    yield put(Action.setIsRunning(false));
    console.log("end try") //I've also try with 'yield console.log("end try")'
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(Action.sendMessageFailed(error));
    yield put(Action.setIsRunning(false));
    console.log("end catch") //also try with 'yield console.log("end catch")'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this is exactly what I was looking for, I clearly had a bad understanding of generator functions.

Comment: You're welcome :) Sagas are very powerful, and can make your life really easy if you understand how the  effects work.